# Not Responsive When Resizing Window, but IS with Google Inspector tools on different devices

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I have been trying to figure this out, and just don't see what is wrong. So frustrating, but wanted to see if anyone can see why when resizing the browser window, the site is not responsive. However, inside of Chrome's and Firefox's inspector tools, I am able to see the website being responsive with different device sizes. I have been using @media screen (max-width) NOT device-width, which I know can cause this issue. I appreciate the help!

```
/***MEDIA QUERIES*****/
@media screen (max-width: 880px) {
  #location-icon {
    margin: 5px 10px 90px 0;
  }
}

@media screen (max-width: 760px) {
  .first-footer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #location-icon {
    margin: 5px 10px 40px 0;
  }

  .copyright {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .first-footer {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media screen (max-width: 375px) {
  .intro {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .intro img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .intro div {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .intro button {
    margin: 40px 0;
  }

  .logo-button button {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
  }

  .logo-button img {
    width: 100px;
  }

  .box {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 30px 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .mid-text {
    order: 2;
    padding: 0;
  }

  #location-icon {
    margin: 5px 10px 100px 0;
  }

  .list1 {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  }

  .list2 {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .icons {
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }

  .copyright {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .first-footer {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I do also have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> at the top of my HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to add "and" when you write a media query with two conditions like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 880px)
```

However the reason it isn't working is due to your container class in the body tag. If you remove it, it will fix most of your issues since there is no reason to use grid in that context

Comment: thanks for getting back and noticing that. with @media there seems to be several different syntaxes I've seen with it and they seem to do the same thing? I've seen people use the "and", without the "and" with screen and without screen. Is this okay?

Comment: I removed the class, but have the issue still. This time the left side of my "header" box is cut off. Not sure why 